# How to Convert RDD[(int, string)] to Dataframe in scala

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I'm using the below code as shown in the snapshot to convert an RDD[(Int, String)] to a DataFrame, while doing so, i'm getting an error saying value split is not a member of (int, string)

val tuple2_maxduration_withdevice is of type RDD[(Int, String)], am i missing any basics here?

Appreciate your help on this request.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Since you already have a tuple, directly use `.toDF()`

```
val result = tuple2_maxduration_withdevice.toDF("duration","device")
```

Comment: Thanks vdep, toDF() was not working on IDE but works fine on Spark-shell. Added the below lines of code(created an instance of sqlContext and toDF("duration","device") works fine on IDE.                                                                                           
  val sqlContext = spark.sqlContext
  import sqlContext.implicits._